# Quotient space of a direct sum of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W_1,W_2\cdot\cdot\cdot W_n$ be invariant subspaces of  a vector space $V.$ Let $$V=W_1\oplus W_2\oplus \cdot\cdot\cdot\oplus W_n$$ be direct sum. Now my question is can i say that $$\frac{V}{W_i}=\frac{W_1\oplus W_2\oplus \cdot\cdot\cdot\oplus W_n}{W_i}\cong W_1\oplus W_2\oplus \cdot\cdot\cdot\oplus W_{i-1}\oplus W_{i+1}\oplus \cdot\cdot\cdot\oplus W_{n}?$$
I am thinking of map like $f:V\rightarrow W_1\oplus W_2\oplus \cdot\cdot\cdot\oplus W_n$ by $f(v)=(w_1,w_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot, w_{i-1},0,w_{i+1},\cdot\cdot\cdot w_n)$ where $v=w_1+w_2+\cdot\cdot\cdot w_n.$ Please suggest me . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several points you need to consider.

First, what do you mean by invariant subspaces? Invariance only has meaning with respect to some transformation. But this should have no bearing on the question.

Second, what do you mean by isomorphism? If you mean as linear spaces, then it is enough to show a bijective linear function between $\frac{W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus ... \oplus W_n}{W_i}$ and $W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus ... W_{i-1}\oplus W_{i+1}  \oplus W_n$.

Keeping this in mind, it is enough to show that if $V = W \oplus U$ then $V/W \simeq U$ (treat $U$ as $W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus ... W_{i-1}\oplus W_{i+1}  \oplus W_n$ and $W$ as $W_i$).

In this case, if $f$ is the linear projection $f(w,u) = (0,u)$ then since $ker(f) = W$, $f$ may be considered as a function from $V/W$ by $\tilde{f}(u + W) = u$. Clearly $\tilde{f}$ is onto since for any $u \in U$, $\tilde{f}(u + W) = u$. Also, $\tilde{f}$ is bijective since for any $u \neq 0$, $\tilde{f}(u + W) = u \neq 0$. Hence, $\tilde{f}$ is a bijective linear map between $V/W$ and $U$ as required.